# Retrieve Data from Just-Inserted Row (MySql and Node.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

if I have a query like the following:

```
var queryString = "INSERT INTO pid SET title = '" + randomTitle + "', poc = '" + random + "';"
connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {

...(do something here)
});
```

, is there a way I can retrieve information for the just-inserted row without performing a new query (in my particular case, I want the auto-generated primary key value).

For instance, can I use the construct with the "query" object (below) and then perhaps use one of the query.on callback to retrieve the information about the just-inserted row?:

```
var query = connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {

    query.on('fields', function(fields) {
    ... get the field information?
    });

    query.on('result', function(row) {
    .. get the field information?
    });


});
```

If not via the query callbacks, is there another way? Thanks for any response!

Answer (score 11):

According to [docs](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row) it is possilbe. Notice that callback function of insert query does not have `rows` and `fields` but only `result` parameter:

```
connection.query(queryString, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
    }
    console.log(result.insertId); // prints inserted id
}
```

Your query is also vulnerable to sql injection. It should look like this:

```
var queryString = "INSERT INTO pid SET title = ?, poc = ?";
connection.query(queryString, [randomTitle, random], function(err, result) {
    // ...
}
```